# Grails update() cannot locate record, show() and edit() can

Tags: grails, db2

I've got a fairly simple Grails app against a DB2 database. Everything works fine except when I try to update a record. show() and edit() are able to find the record , but the update fails saying that it cannot be located. Here's the edit:

```
    def edit() 
{
    def flatAdjustmentInstance = FlatAdjustment.get( new FlatAdjustment(compPayeeID: params["compPayeeID"], effectiveQuarterBeginDate: params["effectiveQuarterBeginDate"]) ) //here are your inbound params

    if(!flatAdjustmentInstance)
    {
        flash.message = "MRI Modifier Record not found with ${params}"
        redirect(action:"list")
    }
    else
    {
        return [ flatAdjustmentInstance: flatAdjustmentInstance]
    }
}
```

Now the update()

```
def flatAdjustmentInstance = FlatAdjustment.get( new FlatAdjustment(compPayeeID: params["compPayeeID"], effectiveQuarterBeginDate: params["effectiveQuarterBeginDate"]) ) //here are your inbound params
    //def flatAdjustmentInstance = new FlatAdjustment(compPayeeID: params["compPayeeID"], effectiveQuarterBeginDate: params["effectiveQuarterBeginDate"])

    if (!flatAdjustmentInstance) 
    {

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'flatAdjustment.label', default: 'FlatAdjustment'), params])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }
```

As I said, all controller methods/closures create the instance of the domain object in the same way and all work correctly except for update(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out, and it was a really bone-headed mistake. The form I had created was passing in the compPayeeID, but since the field is not editable by the user, I changed it from an input to a textField. That meant is was no longer being passed in with the grails params object. I changed it back, set the field to read only, and now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` retrieves an existing object based on its ID. You cannot pass a new object to that method.

`FlatAdjustment flatAdjustmentInstance = FlatAdjustment.findByCompPayeeIDAndEffectiveQuarterBeginDate(params.compPayeeID, params.date("effectiveQuarterBeginDate", "INSERTYOURDATEFORMATHERE"))`

Comment: That sounds correct, however this code is the default Grails scaffolding, and works for the other methods.

Comment: From the Grails user guide - "Retrieves an instance of the domain class for the specified id. null is returned if the row with the specified id doesn't exist."

Comment: I suppose I would need to ask why the same parameters work with the edit but not the update?

Comment: The ID for the object is a composite of `compPayeeID` and `effectiveQuarterBeginDate` ?

Comment: Correct. Defined in the domain as id composite: [compPayeeID, effectiveQuarterBeginDate]

Comment: Updated answer to what it should look like when you need to get an existing object in the database.

Comment: Actuall I am selecting out all fields as Strings since DB2 dates are such a pain in the butt:String compPayeeID
 String metricTypeCode
 String effectiveQuarterBeginDate
 String effectiveQuarterEndDate
 float m12SmtrModifierAmount